# I want to upload an image with first name and last name without refreshing the page in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, upload

```
This is my controller


 function edit_profile() {
        // if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        //{

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $id = $session_data['id'];
        $name = $session_data['name'];




          $uploaddata = null;
                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/userpic';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '10000';
          $Img_name=  strtotime(date("d-m-y H:i:s")).".jpg";
            //$Img_name=  strtotime(date("d-m-y H:i:s"));

              $config['file_name']=    $Img_name ;
                $config['overwrite'] = "true";
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);


                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('documents')) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $uploaddata = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());



                }
         $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
          $file_name =   $name;
           $filepath1= $config['upload_path'];

     if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
      $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lname' => $this->input->post('lastname')
              );
}else
{
    echo "file uploaded";

        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'filepath'=> $Img_name,
            'filename'=>$file_name
        );
}     
        $this->load->model('update_model');
        $this->update_model->update_entry($id, $data); //passing control to update_model
        $session_data['name'] = $this->input->post('firstname');
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data); //settting sesssin values


         if( $data)
                    {
                    $data['message']="Image Uploaded Successfully";
                    $this->load->view('endusers/endemp_edit_profile_view',$data);
                    }
        //redirect('endusers/end_emp_home');
        //}
    }
```

This is my view

```
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('endusers/editprofile/edit_profile');?>
                <table width="auto" border="1" style="border-color: #bce8f1;"class="table table-bordered"  >
                    <tbody>



            <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><input type="text"  class="txt-field uname" name="firstname"  placeholder="first name" required></td>
            </tr>
                                <! ------ <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" class="txt-field pass"  name="lastname"  placeholder="last name" required ></td><br>
            </tr> 

            <tr>

                     <tr>

                            <td valign="top">

                                     <label for="curtexp" style="margin-top: 20px;padding-right: 7px;margin-left: 11px;"> Upload a Profile Picture </label>&nbsp;<label class="error" ></label> 

                                <input type="file" name="documents" size="40" / style="margin-left: 9px;" placeholder="Profile Picture"><br><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8" style="text-align:center">
                                <br />
                                <div class="ee">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" class="buttonmy2" / style="float: left;    margin-bottom: 17px;"> 

                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <input type="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" class="buttonmy2" / style="float: left;margin-left: 10px;"> 
                                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

This is my code in codeigniter for uploading a profile pic but it takes ma to log out to see the uploaded image .I want tom upload a image without logging out of my account and may be jusr refreshing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--This Jquery plugin will solve your problem
--More help http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 


$("#form_id").on('submit', (function (e) {
    var options = { 
            url:'your URL',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            success:function(data){
                 alert('submitted');
            }    
           $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
           e.preventDefault();
}));
```

Comment me if you need help...

Comment: Yes i need help...actually i am new to this thing called ajax and jquery

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>

add this before the form plugin

it simply get all values from the selected form(ID). then pass it to your controller... Please don't add server side validation for ajax submit. 
you can directly get the post values also the image upload.
You can do lot of things with ajax and Jquery.

Comment: ok blackmoon i will try  :) i wil comment here if i need help again. Thank you.